# How to execute my code using terminal without terminal being occupied

Tags: python, terminal, process, background-process

So I've written a headless(without GUI) music player using python and I am currently executing it like this:
`python3 main.py`
I can pause/unpause the running track from inside the program.
but the terminal is occupied , I have to let this extra terminal remain open while I am doing whatever I'm doing and It's kind of bugging me.

How I interact my program now:
*the terminal is occupied so I should terminate my program to free it*

```
:~$python3 main.py
playing track0.mp3: pause 
paused track0.mp3: quit
:~$ls #I terminated the program so I could do this in currently running terminal
```

How I want to interact with my program:the terminal is NOT occupied so I can run other stuff in it.

```
:~$python3 main.py -init #It should not open the program in terminal
:~$ls #so I can do this while the music is playing
:~$python3 main.py pause #and like this I pause the program
:~$nano ~/.bashrc #and again I can use my terminal 
:~$python3 main.py quit #and like this I terminate my program
```

I know it's possible I just don't know how.

Edit:
For anybody who says why don't you use `Ctrl`+`Z` I've got to say it DOESN'T WORK.
I guess it's something about the threads I use inside the program .
I heard somewhere that Pygame doesn't work properly with threading.

Edit:
I tried the following but none of them seem to work:

```
nohup program.py &
program.py &
program.py disown
program.py # and then CTRL Z >> bg
```

Comment: Like you are currently using it seems to make more sense to me than what you intend to do. Why not just open another terminal?

Comment: Do you know that you can suspend and resume running programs with Ctrl-Z and the `bg` and `fg` commands? Would this help you?

Comment: I don't open it because its bugging me. I don't want a paralysed window to pop up whenever I'm ```Alt``+```Tab```ing.

Comment: I tried them / actually before here I asked my question on askubuntu. but they don't work . I guess it's because of double threading or input methods I'm using .

Comment: Depending on which os/platform you are on, you can also use `nohup python3 main.py &` > your program will continue to run even if you close the terminal. Or you can use `python3 main.py &' will be equivalent to Ctrl-Z + bg - this way your stdout of the program will be printed on the terminal even though you are running something else and your program will exit if you close the terminal.

Comment: I tried nohup / & and here is what happens. my program starts muted inside the terminal. when i do CTRL Z and then bg everything goes back to normal. I'm telling you it might be about the threading module I'm using.

Comment: If I understand your question right you can do it by opening a tmux session  or a more complex solution would be to create a docker container and run it in detached mode.